# How to fix browser blob download from maxing RAM?

Tags: javascript, http, web, browser, download

I am trying to download large files (3 gigs) using a post request to my backend. The post request is done to hide the file system from web scraping. It seems like some of the download initially is loaded into memory because the file doesn't initially start downloading, but my ram spikes, then 30 seconds later it begins downloading and slightly lower ram usage. Here is the code I am using.

```
fetch("http://localhost:5000/api/send", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
  "Content-Type": "application/json"
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ "root": root, "path": path, "name": name })
})
.then(response => response.blob())
.then(blob => {
  var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  var a = document.createElement("a")
  a.href = url
  a.download = name
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  a.click()
  a.remove()
})
```

Is there anyway to implement this without a ram/performance hit? Downloading the file as a GET request and using something like `window.location.href = url` works no problem, but I would prefer not to use that, and have difficulties specifying file names with symbols like "&" in the URL parameter.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server respond with a blob, so it’s downloaded into RAM then referred to as an object url on client side.

You see what the client side really need is a url. You don’t have to create it from a blob. Instead you can create a hashed url on server side like "bit.ly/whatever", respond with that url, then client code do the same trick.

Comment: Are you saying to send a post request and then the post request returns a hashed url?

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I suggested

Comment: If you’ve used gcloud storage, that’s exactly their approach.